# How to I declare a query parameter in my kusto dot command query?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I am trying to run this command within c#, but it is returning as syntactically incorrect (which it is according to kusto). My objective is to get all ingestion mappings for a user provided table. How can I rewrite this query to make it syntactically correct?

```
declare query_parameters(table_name:string)
.show table table_name ingestion mappings
```

Answer (score 1):

what you're trying to achieve isn't currently supported: query parameters are only supported in queries, not in control commands.

you can submit/upvote feature requests @ https://aka.ms/adx.ideas